# R webshot package login and redirect: issue with selector

Tags: r, phantomjs, screenshot

A tool we use has regular updates. To keep the screenshots in our documentation up-to-date, I would like to start using Rmd and the webshot package. A first step would be to be able to login (and next to redirect to the desired page).

Based on the example in the package I tried the code below to login, but this triggers an "element not found error".

https://dev79379.service-now.com/login.do is the login page where I took the selectors
https://dev79379.service-now.com/home would be one the urls of interest

So, I have two questions:

1. what would be the correct selector to find the element?
2. how can I redirect from login.do to /home?

   ```
    library(webshot)

    url <- "https://dev79379.service-now.com/home"

    fn <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(url))

    webshot(url, paste0(fn,".png"), 
        useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36", eval = "casper.then(function() {

                // Enter username and password
                this.sendKeys('#user_name.form-control input[type=\"text\"]', 'test');
                this.sendKeys('#user_password.form-control input[type=\"password\"]', 'test');

                // Now click in the search box. This results in a box expanding below
                this.click('#sysverb_login.pull-right.btn.bt-primary input[type=\"submit\"]');

                // Wait 500ms
                this.wait(500);
              });"
   ```

   )

Comment: Oh. That's going to be 'challenging' to say the least! That login page embeds another login form that calls a time stamp.

Comment: Webshot is using phantomJS which is an archived project. It's untouched for 3 years. That places a risk that in a year time something breaks. You may want to look at webshot2 which is using Chrome's headless browser mode. I haven't tested... But I wonder if chrome will share its usual cookies. If so if the login is persistent then logging in on the machine with the browser may be enough, to then allow direct access for the script

Comment: I will take a closer look at the pages when on a proper machine later. Currently on my phone so can't explore elements

Comment: thanks a lot. For the time being webshot2 does not provide an "eval" parameter. In an ideal world I would authenticate using one of the other packages and pass that session to webshot2.

Comment: Chrome Headless - directly from the command line?

Comment: Unfortunately, I will not have access to the command line. The chromote package seems promising. Could you elaborate on the login challenge?

Comment: Sorry, been working. Not sure if you made any progress.  The challenge, is the page you want to show is redirecting to the login because there is no session cookie (at a guess) that says there is a live login.  Can't tell what happens when you do login on a browser? Does it redirect back?

Comment: I am looking into the chromote package which makes taking care of the redirect trivial (as you can login in the viewport and pass the cookie value).